# Remove the date from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

Looking for some Regex help in Ruby.

I have a string that is formated as so:

```
YYYY-MM-DD-title-of-post.markdown
```

I'm looking to use `gsub` or `sub` to remove the `YYYY-MM-DD` portion of the string and do further processing to it.

I would like a Regular Expression to remove the date from the string. The date will never be in a different format.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`new_title = old_title.gsub('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}','')`

Comment: I changed it up a little to get it to work in my case and here is the result: `post = d.gsub(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-/,'')`

Comment: I was *just* about to edit mine to add the `^` and the trailing `-` - good catch. :)

Comment: Also, since I am using a block, I decided to use `gsub!` instead of `gsub`. I'm pretty new to Ruby and am really enjoying it from PHP. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that the date will ALWAYS be in the format YYYY-MM-DD and will ALWAYS appear at the beginning of the string than the following regex will work:

```
my_string = "YYYY-MM-DD-title-of-post.markdown"
date = my_string.match(/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-.*/)[1]
```

Comment: The gsub method would work better as it always returns the string, even if it can not find the REGEX.